# Why is Prerender.io caching many copies of the same page?

Tags: java, angularjs, google-app-engine, prerender

I've been using Prerender.io for over a year now. For a long time, everything was working great. But lately, I've been hitting my 250 cached page limit which has bumped me up to a paying level. But I only have around 30-40 pages to cache. The problem is that the pages are getting cached many times due to some strange nested routing issues.

Here's my actual routing:

```
http://gdgspacecoast.org/#!/about (default)
http://gdgspacecoast.org/#!/news
http://gdgspacecoast.org/#!/events
http://gdgspacecoast.org/#!/activities
http://gdgspacecoast.org/#!/organizers
http://gdgspacecoast.org/#!/photos
```

Here's an example of what's getting cached:

```
200 6.133 s http://gdgspacecoast.org/#!/activities,/photos,/events,/events,/events,/about,/about,/photos    a day ago
200 5.096 s http://gdgspacecoast.org/#!/activities,/events,/photos,/photos,/about,/news a day ago
200 5.025 s http://gdgspacecoast.org/#!/activities,/events,/events,/photos,/activities  a day ago
200 6.144 s http://gdgspacecoast.org/#!/activities,/photos,/activities,/photos  a day ago
200 5.173 s http://gdgspacecoast.org/#!/activities,/events,/photos,/photos,/about,/events   a day ago
200 12.044 s    http://gdgspacecoast.org/#!/activities,/events,/news,/events,/events    a day ago
200 5.353 s http://gdgspacecoast.org/#!/activities,/events,/photos,/photos,/about,/photos   a day ago
200 5.107 s http://gdgspacecoast.org/#!/activities,/photos,/activities,/activities  a day ago
200 5.092 s http://gdgspacecoast.org/#!/activities,/events,/news,/news,/activities  a day ago
200 9.184 s http://gdgspacecoast.org/#!/activities,/photos,/events,/news    a day ago
200 6.997 s http://gdgspacecoast.org/#!/activities,/events,/photos,/news,/activities    a day ago
200 5.135 s http://gdgspacecoast.org/#!/activities,/events,/events,/about   a day ago
200 7.353 s http://gdgspacecoast.org/#!/activities,/photos,/events,/events,/organizers,/events  a day ago
200 5.082 s http://gdgspacecoast.org/#!/activities,/events,/photos,/news,/about a day ago
200 10.53 s http://gdgspacecoast.org/#!/activities,/events,/activities,/organizers,/organizers  a day ago
200 10.174 s    http://gdgspacecoast.org/#!/activities,/events,/activities,/organizers,/events  a day ago
200 13.376 s    http://gdgspacecoast.org/#!/activities,/events,/photos,/news    a day ago
200 10.959 s    http://gdgspacecoast.org/#!/activities,/photos,/events,/events,/events,/news    a day ago
200 7.657 s http://gdgspacecoast.org/#!/activities,/events,/events,/photos,/events  a day ago
200 11.13 s http://gdgspacecoast.org/#!/activities,/events,/news,/events    a day ago
200 6.076 s http://gdgspacecoast.org/#!/activities,/events,/news,/news  a day ago
200 5.507 s http://gdgspacecoast.org/#!/activities,/events,/activities,/organizers,/events,/events,/activities  a day ago
200 5.079 s http://gdgspacecoast.org/#!/activities,/events,/events,/photos,/events,/news    a day ago
200 5.072 s http://gdgspacecoast.org/#!/activities,/photos  a day ago
200 5.076 s http://gdgspacecoast.org/#!/activities,/events,/photos,/photos,/activities  a day ago
200 11.549 s    http://gdgspacecoast.org/#!/activities,/events,/activities,/organizers,/events,/events  a day ago
200 7.405 s http://gdgspacecoast.org/#!/activities,/events,/events,/photos  a day ago
200 8.38 s  http://gdgspacecoast.org/#!/activities,/events,/photos,/photos,/about   a day ago
200 8.153 s http://gdgspacecoast.org/#!/activities,/photos,/activities  a day ago
200 9.109 s http://gdgspacecoast.org/#!/activities,/photos,/events,/events,/organizers  a day ago
200 12.325 s    http://gdgspacecoast.org/#!/activities,/events,/news
```

Here are my filters:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>prerender</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.github.greengerong.PreRenderSEOFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>prerenderToken</param-name>
        <param-value>MYTOKEN</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>prerender</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

I'm using `prerender-java-1.6.2.jar` from https://github.com/greengerong/prerender-java

How do I avoid this behavior so that I am not charged for many times more usage than what I am really using?

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question, and I think your problem is more to do with the behaviour of prerender.io rather than appengine.

Comment: OK. Sorry I have added the fairly obvious question at the end and updated the title. I agree that this is a prerender issue in either the Java side (unlikely since it hasn't changed) or their server side (unknown what is happening there since blog only has the one post).

Comment: In my experience, it's happened on urls in your page that don't prefix with '/', and some crawlers think it is relative paths. and keep looping it.

Comment: It seems your site will accept any URL after the #! and return a result rather than a 404.  For instance 'http://gdgspacecoast.org/#!/events/,/events,/xxx' will return 200, and the body text of the "about" page.

Comment: OK, thank you. I will look into removing the default route or otherwise refining the routing. I'm not sure why this worked as is for 6+ months and only started seeing issues recently. Perhaps it is due to the bots executing more JavaScript now.

Comment: I responded to your email but want to put an answer here in case anyone else runs into a similar case. YOU and Tim Hoffman are correct. You can use our prerender-status-code meta tag to return the correct 404 status code to the crawlers. https://prerender.io/documentation/best-practices

Comment: where did you set the page cache limit ? I read their docs, and it says there's no limit on how many pages it'll cache.

Comment: @coding_idiot I didn't set any limit. That's the free tier limit, beyond that you start getting charged.

Comment: @splaktar. I've been asking prerender's helpdesk this very same question and getting the same run-around seen above. I've got into the habit of deleting old copies because I've seen at least one instance when my webapp was served an out-of-date page.